# is Valid never invoke Custom Validation Attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

```
public class SomeValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public SomeValidator()
        : base("Message")
    {

    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return new ValidationResult("ERROR");
    }
```

And :

```
    [SomeValidator]
    public long Something { get; set; }
```

Why isValid method is never invoked ? (I use ASP MVC 3) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure that you have a controller action taking this model as action argument:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [SomeValidator]
    public long Something { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

or that you call the `UpdateModel`/`TryUpdateModel` method:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new SomeModel();
    if (TryUpdateModel(model))
    {

    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: public override bool IsValid(object value) also not invoking

Comment: @petro, ensure that you have a controller action taking the model with the `Something` property as argument. It is when you invoke this action that the custom validator attribute be called.

Comment: ok thank you that helped -but  is it possible to avoid creating model and calling TryUpdateModel ? I mean to get it working just like any other attribute (Require ,Compare etc.) ?